# Extjs TreeStore data being ignored

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I think I have everything correct here :

**A simple model :**

```
Ext.define('js.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: "name",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "type",
            type: "string"
        }
    ]
});
```

**A tree panel with tree store :**

```
Ext.define('js.packageDialog.ReleaseTreeView.PackageTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    rootVisible: true,
    singleExpand: false,


    initComponent: function () {

        //Ext.create('js.model.MyModel');
        Ext.apply(this, {

            store: new Ext.data.TreeStore({
                model: 'js.model.MyModel',

                "root": {
                    "expanded": true,
                    "name": "",
                    "type": ""
                },
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory'
                    //data: data
                }
            }),
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'treecolumn',
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Parents',
                    dataIndex: 'parents'
                }
            ]
        });
        this.callParent();
    },


    loadData : function() {
        this.store.setRootNode(data);
    }
});
```

**Some data :**

```
var data = Ext.JSON.encode({
    "children": [{
        "type": "folder",
        "name": "Photos",
        "children": [{
            "type": "JPEG",
            "name": "wedding picture"
        }, {
            "type": "JPEG",
            "name": "holiday picture"
        }
        ]
    }]
});
```

I put all this together. See the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/x527x57t/

And nothing is shown in the tree panel. The columns are correct, however my loadData() method does not work.

Comment: `encode` means turn the data into a string.

Comment: got it, thanks :) That was the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have got it to work like so:

```
var data = {
    children: [{
        text: "Photos",
        leaf:false,
        children: [{
            "type": "JPEG",
            text: "wedding picture",
            leaf:true
        }, {
            text: "holiday picture",
            leaf:true
        }]
    }]
};
Ext.define('js.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: "text",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "type",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name:"leaf"
        }
    ]
});

Ext.define('js.packageDialog.ReleaseTreeView.PackageTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    rootVisible: true,
    singleExpand: false,


    initComponent: function () {

        Ext.apply(this, {

            store: new Ext.data.TreeStore({
                model: 'js.model.MyModel',

                root: {
                    expanded: true
                    //type: ""
                },
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory'
                    //data: data
                }
            })

        });
        this.callParent();
    },


    loadData : function() {
        this.store.setRootNode(data);
    }
});
```

So specifying which are leaf nodes in the data, also properties like the root  of your TreeStore was wrapped in quotes, so I just amended. The data is now displaying. This may not be the 'correct' answer but one I can offer so far for you. Hope it helps.